# How can one have a set up with domain name, email and web hosting on different hosts?

Tags: email, dns, domain, google-workspace, web-hosting

I have purchased a domain name from Omnis.com and set up a Google business app for my (custom domain) emails using that domain. I am trying to build and upload a website on a web hosting site (freehostingnoads.com).

Following its setup:

- I set up the mx settings from Google Business ads in the Omnis domain
  control panel
- I configured the name servers on my domain to that of freehostingnoads.com (ns1.freehostingnoads.com to ns4.freehostingnoads.com) on the Omnis domain control panel.

The issue I faced was that after setting up the freehostingnoads.com on my Omnis domain, I stopped receiving mails on the Google Business apps.

I removed the name servers of ns[x=1->4].freehosting.com and set it back to ns[x=1->3].omnis.com, my mails started working again however my website stopped working.

**Is there any way to have both working (email on google and website) using my own domain name (on Omnis)?**

I checked out Google's sites app however I dont wish to use a subdomain for my URL. 
If I can have a free web hosting option I would *prefer* that as im just starting off and dont have much income yet.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the best solution to your issue, but you can point your DNS name servers to Cloudflare, which can then allow you to forward certain requests to other name servers. So, you could set the subdomain "@" (which is the root domain) to the freehostingnoads.com name servers and also point an MX record to Omnis/Google Apps.

Step by step:

1. Go to http://www.cloudflare.com and log in or create an account if you don't already have one. *Only the free plan is needed unless you require extra features on your website, such as CDN-level SSL, SPDY, etc.*
2. Go to https://www.cloudflare.com/my-websites. Add a new website by typing in your domain name (the root level domain you have from Omnis) into the box labeled "e.g. mydomain.com" or something like that. Click "Add Website".
3. CloudFlare will then scan your existing DNS records and ask you to change your DNS settings. When it's done, click "Continue Setup" next to the domain name you just added. **You will need to change your DNS settings from `ns[1,2,3].omnis.com` or `ns[1,2,3,4].freehosting.com` to `lucy.ns.cloudflare.com` and `todd.ns.cloudflare.com`.**
4. You will be shown a page with your domain's DNS settings. Some settings may have already been copied from your existing DNS records, but that is not guaranteed. Here's some of the records you need (since I don't use Google Apps nor Omnis, I'm not quite sure how to proceed from here, but this is my best guess):

   - Add an MX record with name `<yourDomainName(WithoutSuffix)>` and value `ns[1,2,3].omnis.com`. This should re-enable your mails.
   - Add an A record with name `@` (`@` refers to the root domain, i.e. no prefixes, etc.) and value `ns[1,2,3,4].freehosting.com` and this should re-enable your website.

Once the DNS changes have propagated (this may take 24-48 hours), hopefully everything will work.

Comment: It sounds like the author requires an example of how to do this.

Comment: I've added step-by-step instructions.

Comment: Thx for the hint with cloudflare. It's so convenient to manage the DNS settings and has for more options than I had before.

Comment: Point **3.** will differ, though. Cloudflare tells you specifically which nameservers you'll have to use.